# I can't add a second url rewrite in my .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code, and it is working fine, and I need to add one more section

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Za-z]{3,}\s/+coinShowPage\.php\?coinshow=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ coinShowPage.php?coinshow=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I need to add another redirect for another page.  I tried adding this code at the bottom, and it is not working the id field being used below is a string and the one above is numeric if that makes any difference.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Za-z]{3,}\s/+dealerPg\.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ dealerPg.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am not getting a 404 error, it seems like it is not passing the id variable. I am totally lost, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are rewriting everything that matches `^([^/]+)/?$` at the end of your first rule set already.

Comment: Ok, but being new to .htaccess files, I do not know what to change to make it work.